# When and Why to use Refactor>Reorder Parameters

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, refactoring

I am trying to search the answer of this simple question that
In Visual Studio we have a technique 'refactor' sub type Reorder Parameters

When and why do we need to reorder parameters of a certain method? What is the scenario where one has to change the order of parameters of function

Comment: You would reorder parameters when you have numerous overloads of a method and you want to keep the parameter overloads unambiguous and in a logically consistent order.

Comment: @Enigmativity Can you please elaborate it with an example, will be thankful

Comment: There's no functional reason for it, but it's a useful feature for improving code readability, intuitiveness and syntactic logic. It's also handy if you want to add the `params` keyword or specify default parameter values, as these must always appear last in the list.

Answer (score 0):

There are several scenarios in which the reorder is helpful. For example if you need to make one of the parameters of a method optional. It has to then be moved to the end of the list of parameters. Refactor->Reorder allows you to move the parameter and it will update calls to your method everywhere in your code. That relieves the developer from having to fix each individual call.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to reorder parameters to make different methods more consistent in how they are called.  If you have several methods which use the same parameters, or at least a common subset, you may find it more convenient to remember how to call them if the common parameters are all at the start of the parameter list and in the same order.